Why Aren't Violations with Sheriff Triggering Errors? "Help Needed: sheriff.config Rules Not Enforcing as Expected"
I'm trying to use Sheriff to enforces module boundaries and dependency rules in TypeScript, in my Angular project.
I'm having trouble understanding why I don't get an error when the rules defined in sheriff.config are violated. For example, when placing a component from one domain into another, or placing a feature component in the ui or util folders.
Here is my sheriff.config:
export const config: SheriffConfig = {
  version: 1,
  entryFile: 'src/main.ts',
  tagging: {
    src: {
      app: {
        'domains/<domain>': {
          '<type>/*': ['domain:<domain>', 'type:<type>'],
        },
        'shared/<type>/*': ['domain:shared', 'type:<type>'],
        'openapi/<domain>/*': ['domain:<domain>', 'type:util'],
      },
      environments: ['domain:shared', 'type:util'],
    },
  },
  depRules: {
    root: ['*'],
    'domain:*': [sameTag, 'domain:shared'],
    'type:feature': [
      ({ to }) => to.startsWith('type:ui'),
      'type:data',
      'type:util',
    ],
    'type:ui': ['type:data', 'type:util'],
    'type:data': ['type:util'],
    'type:util': noDependencies,
  },
};

And here is the a partial output of  npx sheriff list command:
. (root)
└── src
  ├── app
    ├── domains
      ├── device
        ├── data (domain:device, type:data)
        ├── feature (domain:device, type:feature)
          ├── default-parameters (domain:device, type:feature/default-parameters)
          └── tracker-details (domain:device, type:feature/tracker-details)
        ├── ui (domain:device, type:ui)
        └── util (domain:device, type:util)
      └── gateway
        ├── data (domain:gateway, type:data)
        ├── feature (domain:gateway, type:feature)
          └── gateway-details (domain:gateway, type:feature/gateway-details)
        ├── ui (domain:gateway, type:ui)
        └── util (domain:gateway, type:util)
    ├── openapi
      ├── gateway (domain:gateway, type:util)
        ├── api (domain:gateway/api, type:util)
        └── model (domain:gateway/model, type:util)
    └── shared
      ├── data (domain:shared, type:data)
      ├── feature (domain:shared, type:feature)
      ├── ui (domain:shared, type:ui)
        ├── card (domain:shared, type:ui/card)
      └── util (domain:shared, type:util)
  └── environments (domain:shared, type:util)

Here's the output of npx sheriff verify:
Verification Report

No issues found. Well done!

I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Does anyone have any ideas?
